# Newbie needing help with making a vector

Tags: vector, outline

[image]

Hey guys. Newbie here trying to make a logo for my company. I’ve made the logo on photoshop, got it into Inkscape and am trying to get a vector image. Any time I try...I get all these layers that show on the outline of my image. I just want it to vector as I have it on the original screen if that makes sense. (I feel like it’s a very simple image and this should be so hard) If anyone could help me I would be truly grateful. Thank you.
Marlee[image]

Comment: Hi. Welcome to GDSE. Have you considered recreating it manually. I assume you are auto tracing it. You've discovered one of the main problems with auto tracing - i.e. the results are never as good as manually drawn vectors.

Comment: Didn’t even know that was an option. Thanks for suggesting the idea, I’ll try to figure that out as well :)

Comment: Of course it's an option. What do you think all those tools in the toolbox are for? As for figuring it out, look up tutorials on youtube. There are lots.

Answer (score 1):

If you've performed the Trace Bitmap feature, you may discover that you have various vectors based on colors. It can be confusing enough with a single color trace. Check to ensure that they are ungrouped (control-shift-g) to allow you to attack each vector independently.

Select a vector trace and set the fill to none and set the stroke to the desired color. Check the thickness and set it to as thin as you can see. This will help you distinguish between various vectors more easily.

You should also place these vectors on a layer separate from the image layer. That will allow you to change the transparency of the image to a lower value, making it lighter and in the background. I've found this allows for a more easily adjusted vector.

Additionally, you can place each vector on its own layer and use the tiny eyeball to blink a layer out or in as needed.

It's difficult to determine what else would be helpful without more information.

Comment: Wow thank you for all that advice. I’ll be sure to play around tonight and try to figure it out!